# Livecode: Sort an Array and Display It

Tags: arrays, sorting, livecode

If I have five numeric values in an array, how to sort it by ascending and descending order in livecode?

( CODE ADDED AND UPDATED)

I can sort them in ascending, but how about descending?

```
put 1 into num[1]
put 5 into num[2]
put 3 into num[3]
put 2 into num[4]
put 4 into num[5]

local tSortedArray
local tNextIndex

get the keys of num
sort lines of it by num[each]

split it by return

put 1 into tNextIndex
repeat for each element tIndex in it
put num[tIndex] into sorted[tNextIndex]
add 1 to tNextIndex
end repeat

answer "Sorted in ascending order: "&sorted[1]&", "&sorted[2]&", "&sorted[3]&", "&sorted[4]&", "&sorted[5]&"; Sorted in descending order: "&sortedD[1]&", "&sortedD[2]&", "&sortedD[3]&", "&sortedD[4]&", "&sortedD[5]
```

Expected output:

```
Sorted in ascending order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; Sorted in descending order: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: What you had tried so far? Can you post the code you tried. This is not the place you request code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
sort lines of it numeric descending by tNum[each]
```

By the way "num" is reserved in LiveCode as a short for number so you need to change num[1] etc to something else to get your code working.

Comment: How can I make the output with that code you provided? How can I call it?

Comment: If you use the same code as before but switch the sort into the line above.

Comment: No array value is displayed...
It shows ...
`Sorted in ascending order: ], ], ], ], ]; Sorted in descending order: , , , ,`

Comment: Well that is based on that num is a reserved word in LC. Young to change all your num[] into something else like tNum[]

Answer (score 0):

Sorting arrays in LiveCode can be a bit fiddly. I would convert that array into a list to do the sorting, as below:

0) assume `tNum` is the array to sort

1) convert the array into a list:

`combine tNum using comma`

2) Sort this list either ascending:

`sort items of tNum ascending numeric`

or descending:

`sort items of tNum descending numeric`

3) Convert that list back into an array:

`split tNum using comma`